# Is there a way to add a line to a specific subplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to R, trying to understand how plotting works.

I'm trying to plot a graph consisting of three subgraphs. I use the `par(mfrow=c(1, 3))` to deal with that. But inside a loop, I want to add various lines to the three graphs. How do I choose which of the three subplots I apply the `lines` command to?

As an example, see the code below. All the `lines` commands get applied to the third subgraph, but this is of course not desired. See also the commands `# apply lines to first figure! but how?` and # apply lines to second figure! but how?

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- seq(0, 4, length.out = n) 
no_datasets <- 50

par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
for (i in 1:no_datasets) {
  x <- seq(0, 4, length.out = n) # x <- seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n)
  y <- sin(x)
  errs <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.25) # rnorm(n) generates random numbers whose distribution is normal
  t <- y + errs

  df <- data.frame(x, y, t, errs)

  model1 <- lm(t ~ poly(x, 1), data = df)
  model5 <- lm(t ~ poly(x, 5), data = df)
  model25 <- lm(t ~ poly(x, 25), data = df)

  if (i == 1) {
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")
  }
  t_hat <- predict(model1, df)
  # apply lines to first figure! but how?
  lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")

  t_hat <- predict(model5, df)
  # apply lines to second figure! but how?
  lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")


  t_hat <- predict(model25, df)
  # apply lines to third figure!
  lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the third plot is last, then it is just adding all the lines to the last plot. But if you nest everything in an `if` statement for each plot, then you will get the lines on each respective plot.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- seq(0, 4, length.out = n) 
no_datasets <- 50

par(mfrow=c(1, 3))

for (i in 1:no_datasets) {
  x <- seq(0, 4, length.out = n) # x <- seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n)
  y <- sin(x)
  errs <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.25) # rnorm(n) generates random numbers whose distribution is normal
  t <- y + errs
  
  df <- data.frame(x, y, t, errs)
  
  model1 <- lm(t ~ poly(x, 1), data = df)
  model5 <- lm(t ~ poly(x, 5), data = df)
  model25 <- lm(t ~ poly(x, 25), data = df)
  
  if (i == 1) {
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")
    
    t_hat <- predict(model1, df)
    lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")
  }
  
  if (i == 2) {
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")
    
    t_hat <- predict(model5, df)
    lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")
  }
  
  if (i == 3) {
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")
    
    t_hat <- predict(model25, df)
    lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")
  }  
  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand AndrewGB, it is not possible. So then the answer should be:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100 
no_datasets <- 50

par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
polynomials <- c(1, 5, 25)

x <- seq(0, 4, length.out = n) # x <- seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n)
y <- sin(x)

for (i in 1:length(polynomials)) {
  degree <- polynomials[i]
  for (j in 1:no_datasets) {
    errs <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.25) # rnorm(n) generates random numbers whose distribution is normal
    t <- y + errs
    df <- data.frame(x, y, t, errs)



    model <- lm(t ~ poly(x, degree), data = df)
    if (j == 1) {
      plot(df$x, df$y, xlab = "x", ylab="", col="black", type="l")  
    }
    t_hat <- predict(model, df)
    lines(df$x, t_hat, col="blue")
  }
}
```

[image]